# How concatenation works for a list object within a list?

Tags: python, list, concatenation, sequence

I have a list `x` which contains another `list object` as below:

```
x = [ [1, 0] ]
```

Now, I am performing the concatenation operation on the list `x`

```
a = x + x
a[0][0] = 100

print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[[100, 0], [100, 0]]
```

Here, I have not updated value of `a[1][0]` but it is still modified. What is causing this?

Comment: Python wont do a deep copying when you concatenate lists. Essentially `a[0]` and `a[1]` will point to the same reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: But isn't this `a = x[:] + x[:]` supposed to do a deep copy? Cuz this gives the same result.

Comment: `x[:]` is shallow copy. From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html): Shallow copies of dictionaries can be made using `dict.copy()`, and of lists by assigning a slice of the entire list, for example, `copied_list = original_list[:]`.

Comment: `a = [*x, *x]` too seems to be shallow

Answer (score 2):

because a after concatenation is `[x,x]`
`a[0]` is accessing `x` which is a variable.
and `a[0][0]` is implying to change `x[0]`, thus
changing overall `x`, achieving `[x[0],x[0]]`.

Try to initialize a as `[[1,0],[1,0]]` and run the
same command, you'll see that it'll have your desired
output or `x + x.copy()`

[edit]

this code:

```
x = [5]
y = x.copy()

x[0] += 1

print(x)
print(y)
```

outputs:

```
[6]
[5]
```

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'

Comment: I added a brief example, check it out on the edit.

Comment: `x + x.copy()` would give the same problematic result: `[[100, 0], [100, 0]]`

Answer (score 2):

This is because both elements of `a` are pointing to the same element `x`. Try this very simple example:

```
x = [1,2]
y = x
y[0] = 10
print(x)
```

Surprisingly, the outcome is `[10,2]`. You can avoid this behavior using `copy`, which breaks this relationship and creates a new object.

```
a=x+x
a[0]=a[0].copy()
a[0][0]=100
```

Would do the job.

Comment: But this means every time one wants to change a value one has to first make a copy for that index. There should be an easy way to define `a` as a deepcopy of x + deepcoy of x

Answer (score 2):

Use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

```
from copy import deepcopy

x = [[1, 0]]

a = deepcopy(x) + deepcopy(x)

a[0][0] = 100
```

**Example**

```
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[[100, 0], [1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this to create a copy is:

```
x = [ [1, 0] ]

a = [x[:],x[:]]
a[0][0] = 100

print(a)
```

You can create a new copy to the list instead of reference with `x[:]`.

Output:
`[[100], [[1, 0]]]`

Comment: This is the outcome of your code `[[100], [[1, 0]]]`

Comment: Yes @re-za. I just tested this

Comment: Which is not what OP wants. They want `[[100, 0], [1, 0]]`

Comment: Also note `a = [x[:],x[:]]` gives `[[[1, 0]], [[1, 0]]]` not `[[1, 0], [1, 0]]`

Comment: @re-za The OP didn't specify what they wanted though.

Comment: It's clear in the context. The problem is why the output is `[[100, 0], [100, 0]]` instead of `[[100, 0], [1, 0]]`. At any rate your code gives `[[100], [[1, 0]]]` !

Comment: @re-za So, 100 can't be in a list?

Comment: @re-za Why would OP want [100,0] in [0][0] ? This isn't obvious at all. Instead it looks like they are trying to set the 1st part of the list to 100, and not to [100,0]

Comment: `a[0][0]` is originally 1 and the OP wants to change it to 100. You are getting confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243103/discussion-between-re-za-and-blue-robin).